# Wordnet how to know if string is valid query string

Tags: regex, perl, wordnet

So I'm having trouble calling functions from Wordnet::SenseRelate because some of the "words" in the text are not valid queries. I've tried surrounding with try and catch so that the program doesn't quit and skips it but no luck. I wanted to check if a word was valid by using Wordnet::QueryData but it will quit when i use an invalid word like:

```
$wn->querySense("#44");
```

I get:

```
(querySense) Bad query string: #44
```

Comment: I guess it was conflicting because of the # and the way a query can be said like dog#n#1, I ended up removing the # occurrences...

Answer (score 0):

The regex which is used can be found in the statement:

```
my ($word, $pos, $sense) = $string =~ /^([^\#]+)(?:\#([^\#]+)(?:\#(\d+))?)?$/;
```

If in doubt whether a token will be accepted, test it against this regex.

Commenting on the specific question, there cannot be any leading or trailing # characters (the problem experienced).  If # characters are present, there can be 1 or 2 but not more than 2 in the query string.  The # characters if present as as delimiters to determine what is word, what is pos and what is sense.